# Python fills white spaces in POST data with '+'

Tags: python, http, sharepoint, python-requests

I am using Python's requests module to post some data to my company's SharePoint site:

```
response = requests.post("https//my-sharepoint-site.com", 
                          data={"myPost": "this is a test"},
                          auth=HttpNtlmAuth("\\MY_USER_NAME", MY_PASS))
```

The resulting post on my company's sharepoint site looks like:

```
myPost=this+is+a+test
```

How do I 1) remove "myPost=" and 2) stop the filling of white space with '+' ?

Note: I do not have access to the company's server-side application logic.

Another note: curl does not encode white spaces with '+'. The result of:

```
curl –f –v --ntlm –u MY_USER_NAME --data “this is a test” https://my-sharepoint-site.com
```

is:

```
this is a test
```

Answer (score 1):

You're passing a dict as the `data` parameter, which means the dict is interpreted as key-value pairs to be encoded as `application/x-url-encoded`. URL encoding (such as is used for GET requests) substitutes `+` characters instead of `%20` because that is the behavior of most browsers.

If you want to pass a POST body literally, you need to encode it into bytes yourself.

In your case, simply passing `data="this is a test".encode("utf-8")` should give you the behavior you want.

Comment: My app throws a 415 error when I did data="this is a test".encode("utf-8")

Comment: @Brinley: I don't know SharePoint or your app, but chances are you need to send another header. I would try `Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8`.